# GOG Galaxy 2.0 PSN account (offline)

Tags: python, api, cookies, plugins, integration

**I have been trying to connect my PSN account to Galaxy 2.0 for a while now and it keeps telling me that it's (offline), I have tried the solutions that come up first on a google search and they didn't work for me.**

**All the solutions I found have a different code (I don't have it) than the one the app installs by default or the one I can find on Github.**

**I will provide the code that I have which is the one the app installed by default.**
**If you have any solutions or know how to solve this please help me, thanks in advance.**

**This is the log in case it is needed**
https://www.mediafire.com/file/3b3921wgyq9357m/plugin-psn-38087aea-3c30-439f-867d-ddf9fae8fe6f.log/file

````
import sys
from typing import List, Any, AsyncGenerator

from galaxy.api.consts import Platform, LicenseType
from galaxy.api.errors import InvalidCredentials
from galaxy.api.plugin import Plugin, create_and_run_plugin
from galaxy.api.types import Authentication, Game, NextStep, SubscriptionGame, \
    Subscription, LicenseInfo

from http_client import HttpClient
from http_client import OAUTH_LOGIN_URL, OAUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
from psn_client import PSNClient

from version import __version__

AUTH_PARAMS = {
    "window_title": "Login to My PlayStation\u2122",
    "window_width": 536,
    "window_height": 675,
    "start_uri": OAUTH_LOGIN_URL,
    "end_uri_regex": "^" + OAUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL + ".*"
}


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class PSNPlugin(Plugin):
    def __init__(self, reader, writer, token):
        super().__init__(Platform.Psn, __version__, reader, writer, token)
        self._http_client = HttpClient()
        self._psn_client = PSNClient(self._http_client)
        logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.FATAL)

    async def _do_auth(self, cookies):
        if not cookies:
            raise InvalidCredentials()

        self._http_client.set_cookies_updated_callback(self._update_stored_cookies)
        self._http_client.update_cookies(cookies)
        await self._http_client.refresh_cookies()
        user_id, user_name = await self._psn_client.async_get_own_user_info()
        if user_id == "":
            raise InvalidCredentials()
        return Authentication(user_id=user_id, user_name=user_name)

    async def authenticate(self, stored_credentials=None):
        stored_cookies = stored_credentials.get("cookies") if stored_credentials else None
        if not stored_cookies:
            return NextStep("web_session", AUTH_PARAMS)

        auth_info = await self._do_auth(stored_cookies)
        return auth_info

    async def pass_login_credentials(self, step, credentials, cookies):
        cookies = {cookie["name"]: cookie["value"] for cookie in cookies}
        self._store_cookies(cookies)
        return await self._do_auth(cookies)

    def _store_cookies(self, cookies):
        credentials = {
            "cookies": cookies
        }
        self.store_credentials(credentials)

    def _update_stored_cookies(self, morsels):
        cookies = {}
        for morsel in morsels:
            cookies[morsel.key] = morsel.value
        self._store_cookies(cookies)

    async def get_subscriptions(self) -> List[Subscription]:
        is_plus_active = await self._psn_client.get_psplus_status()
        return [Subscription(subscription_name="PlayStation PLUS", end_time=None, owned=is_plus_active)]

    async def get_subscription_games(self, subscription_name: str, context: Any) -> AsyncGenerator[List[SubscriptionGame], None]:
        yield await self._psn_client.get_subscription_games()

    async def get_owned_games(self):
        def game_parser(title):
            return Game(
                game_id=title["titleId"],
                game_title=title["name"],
                dlcs=[],
                license_info=LicenseInfo(LicenseType.SinglePurchase, None)
            )

        def parse_played_games(titles):
            return [{"titleId": title["titleId"], "name": title["name"]} for title in titles]

        purchased_games = await self._psn_client.async_get_purchased_games()
        played_games = parse_played_games(await self._psn_client.async_get_played_games())
        unique_all_games = {game['titleId']: game for game in played_games + purchased_games}.values()
        return [game_parser(game) for game in unique_all_games]

    async def shutdown(self):
        await self._http_client.close()


def main():
    create_and_run_plugin(PSNPlugin, sys.argv)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()```
````